# Creating a cuboid in webgl(not a cube)

Tags: webgl

Can anyone provide me with a full webgl code to create a cuboid(not a cube)??

i am trying to use the following coordinates in init buffers()

```
    cuboidVertexPositionBuffer1 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cuboidVertexPositionBuffer1);
    vertices = [
        //front face
        0.0,      0.0,    0.0,
        0.0154,   0.0,    0.0,    //X
        0.0154,   0.062,  0.0,
        0.0,      0.062,  0.0,


        // Back face
        0.0,      0.0,   -0.04,
        0.0,      0.062, -0.04,    
        0.0154,   0.062, -0.04,
        0.0154,   0.0,   -0.04,


        // Top face
        0.0,      0.062, -0.04,
        0.0,      0.062,  0.0,
        0.0154,   0.062,  0.0,
        0.0154,   0.062, -0.04,


        // Bottom face
        0.0,      0.0,   -0.04,
        0.0154,   0.0,   -0.04,      //Y
        0.0154,   0.0,    0.0,
        0.0,      0.0,    0.0,


        // Right face
        0.0154,   0.0,   -0.04,
        0.0154,   0.062,   -0.04,
        0.0154,   0.062,  0.0,
        0.0154,   0.0,    0.0,


        // Left face
        0.0,      0.0,   -0.04,
        0.0,      0.0,    0.0,
        0.0,      0.062,  0.0,
        0.0,      0.062, -0.04
        ];

       gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    cuboidVertexPositionBuffer1.itemSize = 3;
    cuboidVertexPositionBuffer1.numItems = 24;



    cuboidVertexIndexBuffer1 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cuboidVertexIndexBuffer1);
    var cubeVertexIndices = [
        0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
        4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
        8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
        12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
        16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
        20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    cuboidVertexIndexBuffer1.itemSize = 1;
    cuboidVertexIndexBuffer1.numItems = 36;
```

The problem is in the right side ,when i rotate the camera X merges with Y as degree of rotation increases.

Comment: *Can anyone provide me with a full webgl code to create a cuboid(not a cube)??* **NO. Stack overflow is not a code writing service**.

Comment: that's why i added coordinates and added the description so that anyone could check them for any problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my mistake actually there wasn't any mistake in the coordinates the problem was due to the near screen clipper.I just changed its value and it worked.

Comment: In that case, your error is a non-reproducible one, and neither your question nor your answer are going to help anyone -- please delete both !